# Arduino boolean array; 1 true and the rest false

Tags: arrays, arduino, boolean

I have a question about arduino considering a setup with 8 leds and an potentiometer. I want to let 1 led light up, which is the led that matches the value returned by the potentiometer, and the rest of the leds should be turned off. Furthermore, when I change the position of the potentiometer, the leds should change accordingly. So far ive got this:

```
for(int i = 0; i)
{
    if (i = draaiKnopStand)
    {
        status[i] = HIGH;
    }
    else
    {
        status[i] = LOW;
    }

    digitalWrite(draaiKnopStand, status[i]);
}
```

Comment: Do you the all the leds to light up like a stack according to potentiometer value or just the unique led in position that fits the value from potentiometer?

Comment: just the unique led in position that fits the value from potentiometer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering this is [Arduino Uno Front](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno)

I have no Arduino here in my job. I did this using a simulator. Please try it:

```
int _potentiometer = 9; // Potentiometer - Analog Pin
int _val = 0;
int _borderLineVal = 0;
int ledPins[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }; // an array of pin numbers to which LEDs are attached
int pinCount = 6; // the number of pins (i.e. the length of the array)

void setup() {
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++)  {
        pinMode(ledPins[thisPin], OUTPUT);      
    }
}

void loop() {
    _val = analogRead(_potentiometer); //reading the Potentiometer value interval: 0 - 1023
    _borderLineVal = (int)(1023 / pinCount);
    Serial.println(_val);

    // turn all leds off
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[thisPin], LOW);
    }

    // turn the select led on
    if(_val > 0){
        _pinHigh = (int)(1023 / _borderLineVal);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[_pinHigh], HIGH); // turn the pin on
    }
}
```